# How can I print out a list of the keys in a hashmap?

Tags: java

I am storing objects in a hashmap and want to be able to see what I have in the hashmap. That is, If I want to view or change one of my objects, I want to print out a list of the keys so that I can see the choices available to me.

Here is how I put the keys into a printable format.

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(allDogs.keySet());
```

That is at the beginning of my code. I would then declare some objects in this way.

```
System.out.println("\nWhat is the customer's name?");
custName = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("What is the dog's name");
name  = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("What is the dog's breed?");
breed  = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
age  = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();

System.out.println("Does the dog have a valid rabies vaccine (Y/N)?");
vaccinated=false;
String invax = in.nextLine();
if (invax.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1).equals("Y")) 
    vaccinated=true;

allDogs.put(custName, new Dog(name, breed, age, vaccinated));
```

Then later on I may want to view some dog's information so I do this.

```
System.out.println("\nWhat is the customers name?");
System.out.println(keys);
custName = in.nextLine();

while(allDogs.get(custName) == null)
{
    System.out.println("That is not a valid name. Please try again");
    custName = in.nextLine();
}

System.out.println(allDogs.get(custName));
```

The problem is that when it prints out keys, all I get is an empty list.

```
[]
```

The weird part is that I was just doing this and it worked and I don't know what I changed.

I just realized what may have been different and it was that when I try to print the list that line is in an if statement. If I move the declaration of the list into the if statements then it works. So how can I make it work so that I only declare the list once and at the top of my code instead of inside the if statements?

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are declaring and initialzing your keyset right at the beginning.How about you declare it there.And initialize its values whewnever you want to display the keySet.Or else it was always contain  the keys which were initially present. i.e. 0

Comment: @Shade23 I understand that. I think you are right. The only thing is I'm not sure how I initialize and declare separately. What is the syntax for initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right and you simply wanna print out the contents of a map, then just use it's toString method?

```
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

How you want it printed:

```
map.keySet().toString()
```

Comment: This prints out everything. That is it shows all attributes of each object when I just want it to print out the keys so I can see my "choices".

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the simplest way to do what I am trying to achieve. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you are creating the list of keys as a **copy** of the keyset not as a **reference** to the keyset. So, as you update the map, the list won't update along with it.

The fix is to put the keys in printable format *after* filling the map.

Comment: +1. Or to avoid using a separate list completely, and print the keySet of the map directly.